# How to make Vuforia stop tracking in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I've been looking for a way to stop Vuforia engine from tracking, and googleing didn't help at all.

I wanted to stop tracking when I found a tracker, and then resume trackng after an event (like a button click).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used to accomplish what you need. (:

```
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>().Stop();
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>().Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally Visual Studio's IntelliSense helped me with this. You can disable a tracker in a single line of code calling

```
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker(Tracker.Type.IMAGE_TRACKER).Stop();
```

Similarly, to start it again

```
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker(Tracker.Type.IMAGE_TRACKER).Start();
```

Comment: This code doesn't work anymore:
`'Tracker' does not contain a definition for 'Type'`
`No overload for method 'GetTracker' takes '1' arguments`
I guess there is some generic involved but coundn't get it to work.

Comment: maybe `TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>()`?

Comment: tinchou you are right - I've tried it before but it didn't work, now I realize it doesn't work in the editor, only on real device.

Answer (score 1):

This code will disable the tracker

```
mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    
if (mTrackableBehaviour)
{
  mTrackableBehaviour.UnregisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
}
```

This code will enable the tracker

```
mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    
if (mTrackableBehaviour)
{
   mTrackableBehaviour.registerTrackableEventHandler(this);
}
```

Comment: What is difference between enabling and disabling tracker?

Answer (score 0):

only this code will enable the tracker

```
mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();

if (mTrackableBehaviour){
    mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
}
```

May i know the reason for 2 seconds delay.the scanline delay two seconds initially during the load of the app.