# How do I stop tracking in Vuforia for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, tracking, vuforia

I'm trying to stop Vuforia from tracking but doesn't stop the camera.

I found this answer but it doesn't seem to work.
[How to make Vuforia stop tracking in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087725/how-to-make-vuforia-stop-tracking-in-unity/17087726#17087726)

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check tag definitions... I'm not sure, but they do not seem adeguate for your context / problem.

Comment: You can just deactivate the GameObject itself to which the tracking script is attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just solved using:

```
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop();
```

Don't forget to add:

```
using Vuforia;
```

Answer (score 4):

To have a bit more control on which tracker you want to use, adjust the following:

```c#
if (TrackerManager.Instance != null)
        {
            //Positional DeviceTracker
            if (TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>() != null)
                TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>().Stop();

            //Rotational DeviceTracker
            if (TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<RotationalDeviceTracker>() != null)
                TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<RotationalDeviceTracker>().Stop();

             //Object Tracker
            if (TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>() != null)
                TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop();
        }
```

You can simply *Stop* and *Start* which ever tracker you need.

Comment: where exactly do I call this? I call it in the MarkerDetection.cs in the OnTrackingFound() method.. it doesn't stop the camera, but it doesn't even place/display the marker child objects, even though it says "Trackable myMarker found".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

To stop tracking:

```c#
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop();
```

To start tracking:

```c#
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Start();
```

import in your script `using Vuforia;` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used to accomplish my requirements :)

```
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>().Stop();
TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>().Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can stop vuforia tracking by adding ..**

```
ObjectTracker objectTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
objectTracker.TargetFinder.Stop();
```

Also add namespace 
**using Vuforia;**